Problem with trailing number using adodb to import csv file
I use adodb to import csv to sheet but i have problem with trailing minus data and it seem record set cannot recognize trailing minus and it disappear.
i want it to import negatve number but because they are trailing minus number, it doesn't work. I can't use query table because i want to work with large file and query table is too slow. I don't want to work with power query too.
Here is a part of my code
Dim conn As Object
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim recordSet As Object
Set recordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

'Create Schema file
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strFilePath & "\\Schema.ini")
oFile.WriteLine ("[" & strFileName & "]")
oFile.WriteLine ("Format=Delimited(;)")
oFile.WriteLine ("ColNameHeader=True")
oFile.WriteLine ("CharacterSet=OEM")
oFile.WriteLine ("MaxScanRows=25")

and i copy it to my sheet
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1,FMT=Delimited(;)"""
End With

conn.Open

recordSet.Open "SELECT * from " & strFileName, conn, 3, 1

Dim copyRng As Range
Set copyRng = ws.Range("A2")
With ws
    .UsedRange.ClearContents
    .Range("A1:Z1") = headers
    
    copyRng.CopyFromRecordset recordSet
...
end with

i want to include negative number to the sheet

Would help to show a sample of the file you're importing.

i can't, because it is related to my company's work. However here is some examples: The negative number is in this format: 3224- instead -3224, 2- instead -2

Are the numbers in specific columns?

yes, some columns store numbers (exp. 1234,00)

Maybe use the schema.ini file to import those columns as "text" and then fix the content once it has been imported?   If the numbers are currency then schema.ini has support for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#:~:text=a%20currency%20amount.-,CurrencyNegFormat,-Can%20be%20one
